# Is it safe to delete unused Application Insights resources from the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We have a number of Application Insights resources, most of which were created automatically when App Services were created. Most of them are not being used. Is it safe to delete the Application Insights resources without affecting the rest of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, app insights resources are separate services in their own right, and only tied to your application by the application Id (or "key") that's published in the app insights resource blade.

Comment: That's what I'd hoped - is this based on personal experience or do you have a link to any documentation about this. I can't find anything.

Comment: Based on Experience :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check that no application is linked to it and if yes, you can remove it safely without any issues.

Comment: There are applications linked to them but I'm fine with losing the Application Insights data - just not the application itself.

Comment: In this case, App insights may generate errors as it will always try to upload the statistics data, you should remove the link first from your Apps

Comment: I've not experienced any errors when doing this - do you know where those errors would be visible?

Comment: App Insights adds some JavaScript to the page to send timings of the page render and load to Azure, also as far as I know, it does the same server side. So, if you are not using it, why should you keep it and adds overhead to your App?