# Is it ok to delete an Azure Application Insights resource

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have inherited an Azure subscription that is 4 basic App Services (websites). It has two Application Insights resources in it (both for the same App service - go figure).

Is there any problem if I delete these? The 4 websites are all running fine and are very low traffic.

**Update:** This is a different question from the one linked as a duplicate. This question asks about deleting an **Application Insights** resource while the [supposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67952933/is-it-ok-to-delete-an-azure-log-analytics-workspace/67958682#67958682) asks about deleting a **log analytics workspace** resource.

Comment: I'd recommend to open Logs experience for Application Insights resource and explore whether there are any records there. If not then I don't think deleting the resource will harm anything.

Comment: It definitely will not break App Service (websites). The worst thing is that you will stop getting telemetry. But if you haven't got anything for the retention period (default value is 90 days) then most likely nobody is submitting telemetry there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there wont be any problem if you delete the unused application Insights

For Further more Information you can refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139390/is-it-safe-to-delete-unused-application-insights-resources-from-the-azure-portal) and here is the Link that would help you to [delete Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/remove-application-insights?tabs=net).